# Text is not clearly visible in TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in android. I am designing a login page.

This is my xml:-

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_weight="1" 
   android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
   android:id="@+id/loginlayout" 
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
   android:soundEffectsEnabled="false">

   <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white" 
      android:padding="20dp" 
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/Text_UID" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="User Id" 
         android:textColor="#000000" 
         android:textSize="8pt" />
      </TextView>

      <EditText
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/EditText_UID" 
         android:layout_width="200dp" 
         android:background="@drawable/text_box">
      </EditText>

      <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/Text_UID" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:textColor="#000000" 
         android:text="Password"  
         android:textSize="8pt">
      </TextView>

      <EditText 
         android:text="" 
         android:id="@+id/EditText_Pass" 
         android:layout_width="200dp" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:background="@drawable/text_box">
      </EditText>

      <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_height="35px" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

         <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Login" 
            android:id="@+id/Button_Submit" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button_Register"  
            android:background="@drawable/button_register_right"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:textSize="5pt">
         </Button>
      </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

whenever i enter user name then it is visible to user, but when i enter password then the entered text is not visible till the android device keyboard is active. When i press back button to remove android device keyboard then it is visible means password dot visible to user. 
but when i run this project on system then both userid and password both are visible. please suggest me what should i do for this. is this matter of device dependent ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this attribute in your Password EditText :

```
 android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: this is problem related to appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_weight="1" 
   android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
   android:id="@+id/loginlayout" 
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
   android:soundEffectsEnabled="false">

   <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white" 
      android:padding="20dp" 
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/Text_UID" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="User Id" 
         android:textColor="#000000" 
         android:textSize="8pt" />

      <EditText
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/EditText_UID" 
         android:layout_width="200dp" 
         android:background="@drawable/text_box"/>

      <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/Text_UID" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:textColor="#000000" 
         android:text="Password"  
         android:textSize="8pt"/>

      <EditText 
         android:text="" 
         android:id="@+id/EditText_Pass" 
         android:layout_width="200dp" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:background="@drawable/text_box" 
         android:inputType="textPassword"/>

      <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_height="35px" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

         <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Login" 
            android:id="@+id/Button_Submit" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button_Register"  
            android:background="@drawable/button_register_right"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:textSize="5pt">
         </Button>
      </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

you forget to set the input into the password field

Comment: i know sir that i didnt write the  android:inputType="textPassword". my problem is not this. my problem is that whenever i enter a text in the second editText then the keyboard of device overlap it and it is not visible .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the weight attribute from your outermost `LinearLayout`, and have you tried wrapping the whole thing in a `ScrollView`?